# Group by column and have a column with a value_counts dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a sales table with customer purchase history. I want to make a new dataframe grouped by customer. The dataframe should also include a column with a value_counts dictionary of all the products that customer has purchased and the count of how many of each product.

I have done the below:

`categories = data.groupby(by=['CustomerID']).Description.value_counts().to_frame().rename(columns={'Description':'Counts'}).reset_index(level='Description')`

which produces this:

```
              Description          Counts
CustomerID
3004000304    MAJOR APPLIANCES     3
3004000304    HOME OFFICE          2
3004000304    ACCESSORIES          1
3004002756    MAJOR APPLIANCES     1
3004002946    HOME OFFICE          2
3004002946    ACCESSORIES          1
3004002946    MAJOR APPLIANCES     1
```

I've tried seeing if I could fix the above dataframe like this:

`categories['Merged'] = categories.apply(lambda x: {x['Description']:x['Counts']}, axis=1)`

which gives me this:

```
              Description          Counts   Merged
CustomerID
3004000304    MAJOR APPLIANCES     3        {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 3}
3004000304    HOME OFFICE          2        {'HOME OFFICE': 2}
3004000304    ACCESSORIES          1        {'ACCESSORIES': 1}
3004002756    MAJOR APPLIANCES     1        {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
3004002946    HOME OFFICE          2        {'HOME OFFICE': 2}
3004002946    ACCESSORIES          1        {'ACCESSORIES': 1}
3004002946    MAJOR APPLIANCES     1        {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
```

but I want this:

```
              Counts
CustomerID
3004000304    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 3, 'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 1}
3004002756    {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
3004002946    {'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
```

Some assistance to produce the above dataframe would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function with `zip` and `dict`:

```
f = lambda x: dict(zip(x['Description'], x['Counts']))
df = categories.groupby(level=0).apply(f).to_frame('Counts')
print (df)
                                                       Counts
CustomerID                                                   
3004000304  {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 3, 'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACC...
3004002756                            {'MAJOR APPLIANCES': 1}
3004002946  {'HOME OFFICE': 2, 'ACCESSORIES': 1, 'MAJOR AP...
```